# Calculating product's quantity with nested EF Query

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I want to calculate the quantity of every product. I want to use these tables for this.

[image: My Tables]

I want take result like this.

---

StockId | StockName | Sum(ProductNumber) [actually product quantity]

---

I tried this code for can take right result but It is returning null value even though it is the condition that satisfies the conditions.

```
CimriContext context = new CimriContext();
    public ICollection<StockDto.StockHeader> FillDataGrid(int userCompanyId)
    {
        ICollection<StockDto.StockHeader> Stocks = context.Stocks.Where(c => c.UserCompanyId==userCompanyId).
             Select(c => new StockDto.StockHeader()
             {
                 StockId = c.StockId,
                 StockName = c.StockName,
                 Piece=0
             }).ToList();

        ICollection<StockDto.StockHeader> ProductHeader = new List<StockDto.StockHeader>();
        foreach (var products in Stocks)
        {
            products.Piece = context.ProductTransactions.Where(p => p.StockId==products.StockId).Sum(s => s.ProductNumber);
            ProductHeader.Add(products);
        }

        return ProductHeader.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean "Price"? If not: what's the product's "piece"? It's components, stock, etc.?

Comment: In your case "Number" = "Quantity" I assume?

Comment: I want to mean number of products. Yeah you are right

Comment: break point koyup tek tek denesenya neresi boş geliyor , örneğin ` ICollection<StockDto.StockHeader> ProductHeader = new List<StockDto.StockHeader>();` kodunun olduğu yere koy , bir bak bakalım Stocks doluyor mu mesela

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd use the term "Quantity" then. A product number is usually something like a model number or an ID.

Comment: @gencklavyeler Please use only English on this site for other people to benefits.  Stock instance is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to retrieve `ProductCount` for per stock record. You can perform it by joining two tables and grouping `StockId` and `StockNumber` like this;

```
        var query = from stocks in context.Stocks 
                    join products in context.ProductTransactions ON stocks.StockId equals products.StockId
                    where stocks.UserCompanyId = userCompanyId
                    group stocks by new
                    {
                        stocks.StockId,
                        stocks.StockName
                    } into gcs
                    select new
                    {
                        StockId = gcs.Key.StockId,
                        StockName = gcs.Key.StockName,
                        ProductCounts = gcs.Count()
                    };
```

Comment: Why is stockName equal to gcs.Key?

Comment: I edited your code according to my app but it is returning null again.

Comment: For see my code [link](https://image.prntscr.com/image/efiuCMjuQeq4VTO0otViKg.png)

Comment: Would you provide exception detail ?

Comment: `ICollection<StockDto.StockHeader> products = bStock.FillDataGrid(userCompanyId);
 mainForm.mdgProducts.DataSource = products;//exception is here`
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: "mainForm.mdgProducts" Is it null ? Did you debug these objects ?